# My banner appears in visual studio, but doesn't appear when I upload the site.master. Why is this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, blogengine.net

I have a site.master in my root, and a site.master in my /blog/ directory.

I want to modify the site.master in my /blog/ directory to make my site look as uniform as possible.  So I started by putting my banner in the coding, which looks great in Visual Studio.

But when I upload the edited site.master, although the favicon shows up, the banner completely disappears -- like it's not there.

My coding in my /blog/ site.master is this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="~/img/RTN_favicon.GIF" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-min.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<form runat="Server" class="body">
<div id="header">
    <asp:Image ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/RTN_banner.jpg" 
    Style="height: 250px; width: 960px;" NavigateUrl="~/" />
    &nbsp;<p>
        <a href="<%=Utils.AbsoluteWebRoot %>">
            <%=BlogSettings.Instance.Name %>
        </a>
    </p>
    <span>
        <%=BlogSettings.Instance.Description %></span>
</div>
```

In VS, the RTN_banner shows up, but when I go to upload this, it's like the banner isn't there -- there's not even a 960 x 250 empty space! But my **favicon** shows up.  Does anybody have any idea why I cannot get RTN_banner to show up?  Thank you for any guidance!

**EDIT:**
Here's a picture of my properties for the /blog/ site.master banner.  What's peculiar is that there's no behavior for "**Enabled**", like all my other pictures do.  In my root site.master, there is a behavior set to "**true**" ... I don't know if this is the issue or not.

[image: Banner Properties]

Comment: Is it set to content in visual studio?

Comment: I'm unsure as to what you mean, Luke ... I just used my VS toolbox to insert the hyperlinked banner ...

Comment: Go have a look at where it has put the banner image file in your solution, if you right click it and go to the properties there is an option to tell VS what to do with the file. If its not set to content it wont build it into the deploy package which means it wont be on your server for the browser to render.

Comment: Hi Luke.  Thanks again for taking the time to help.  I just put a picture of my VS properties in my question.  Notably absent was there is no behavior for "Enabled" set to true, like my other banner has in my root site.master.

Comment: Solved .... I'll answer my own question.  Thanks for your help again Luke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image file should be a part of your project and there is an option that tells Visual Studio to include the file in an output package.

The image file is located in `~/img/RTN_banner.jpg` according to your code. If you view the properties of this file, you can set the *Build Action* to *Content*. That way, the image file will be copied to your server and it will show online.

You can find the MSDN documentation for this property here: [File Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Wouter ... I posted how I solved this at the same time as you posted your answer.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond, and I've already bookmarked the link you gave me and I'm going to read through it so I can understand this a little better.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug in VS, but I noticed that this code:

```
 <asp:Image ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/RTN_banner.jpg" 
Style="height: 250px; width: 960px;" NavigateUrl="~/" />
```

Which is what my toolbox inserted into the code when I inserted the image.  /blog/img/RTN_anner.jpg which doesn't exist; it didn't look in my root/img/RTN_banner.jpg.

I just solved this by putting in the absolute path to the image, and now things work properly.

```
     <asp:Image ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
     ImageUrl="http://domain.org/img/RTN_banner.jpg" Style="height: 250px; 
     width: 960px;" NavigateUrl="~/" />
```